# Populate Combobox from a web Combobox accesed with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium

I am trying to populate a Combobox in a WinForms Application with text and values extracted from a website.

**CODE - Selenium  using Visual Studio**

```
List<IWebElement> options = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='id_object']/option")).ToList();
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(options.ToArray());
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<select name="id_object" id="object" style="width:100%;">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">-- Pick one --</option>
        <option value="123">First</option>
        <option value="1245">Second</option>
        <option value="157">Third</option>
        ....
</select>
```

However, the combobox gets populated with the following values and it doesn't seem to relate to the values in html code.

[image]

It seems to be a kind of formatting issue.

How can I populate the combobox, with text and values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the text and attribute value and then add those into `ComboBox`.

```
List<IWebElement> options = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='id_object']/option"));
for (int i = 0; i < options.Count; i++)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(options.ElementAt(i).Text + " , " + options.ElementAt(i).GetAttribute("value"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sendkeys to populate the combobox

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32771004)